# Dummy Variable for each year

Tags: r

If I have the following data.frame, how would I go about creating a dummy variable for each year and attach it to DF so there would be additional columns year2010 and year2011.  I have a fairly large dataset with many different years and I don't want to use ifelse 50 times.  ddply?

Thanks

```
 DF <- read.table(text=" year     id     var     ans
     2010      1      1       1
     2010      2      0       0
     2010      1      0       1
     2010      1      0       1
     2011      2      1       1
     2011      2      0       1
     2011      1      0       0
     2011      1      0       0", header=TRUE)
```

Desired output :

```
  year id var ans year_2010 year_2011
1 2010  1   1   1         1         0
2 2010  2   0   0         1         0
3 2010  1   0   1         1         0
4 2010  1   0   1         1         0
5 2011  2   1   1         0         1
6 2011  2   0   1         0         1
7 2011  1   0   0         0         1
8 2011  1   0   0         0         1
```

1

Comment: In DF, you already have `year`. Is this something you expect? Or is this a part of DF?

Comment: @jazzurro I need dummy variable columns differentiating the years.

Comment: Please show your desired output with this sample input.

Comment: I wonder if simple `DF$year = factor(DF$year)` would be sufficient for you and it would not be necessary to create dummy variables at all. Linear regression in R understands factor variables as categorical.

Comment: @AndreyShabalin I tried this and it didn't work.  Thanks though

Comment: 'Did not work` is pretty vague. Anyway, good luck.

Comment: @AndreyShabalin didn't work as in didn't produce my desired results. It actually didn't do anything to my data.frame

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use `table`, like this:

```
cbind(DF, as.data.frame.matrix(table(sequence(nrow(DF)), DF$year)))
  year id var ans 2010 2011
1 2010  1   1   1    1    0
2 2010  2   0   0    1    0
3 2010  1   0   1    1    0
4 2010  1   0   1    1    0
5 2011  2   1   1    0    1
6 2011  2   0   1    0    1
7 2011  1   0   0    0    1
8 2011  1   0   0    0    1
```

---

You should also be able to do something like this:

```
library(data.table)
cbind(DF, 
      dcast.data.table(as.data.table(DF, keep.rownames = TRUE), 
                       rn ~ year, value.var = "id", fun.aggregate = length))
#   year id var ans rn 2010 2011
# 1 2010  1   1   1  1    1    0
# 2 2010  2   0   0  2    1    0
# 3 2010  1   0   1  3    1    0
# 4 2010  1   0   1  4    1    0
# 5 2011  2   1   1  5    0    1
# 6 2011  2   0   1  6    0    1
# 7 2011  1   0   0  7    0    1
# 8 2011  1   0   0  8    0    1
```

If you want the names to be "year_2010" and so on, I guess a workaround would be to do something like this:

```
dcast.data.table(as.data.table(DF, keep.rownames = TRUE)[, yr := "year"], 
                 rn ~ yr + year, value.var = "id", fun.aggregate = length)
```

---

You can also always write your own function. Here's one I've whipped together that should be reasonably efficient:

```
dummyCreator <- function(invec, prefix = NULL) {
  L <- length(invec)
  ColNames <- sort(unique(invec))
  M <- matrix(0L, ncol = length(ColNames), nrow = L,
              dimnames = list(NULL, ColNames))
  M[cbind(seq_len(L), match(invec, ColNames))] <- 1L
  if (!is.null(prefix)) colnames(M) <- paste(prefix, colnames(M), sep = "_")
  M
} 

dummyCreator(DF$year, prefix = "year")
#      year_2010 year_2011
# [1,]         1         0
# [2,]         1         0
# [3,]         1         0
# [4,]         1         0
# [5,]         0         1
# [6,]         0         1
# [7,]         0         1
# [8,]         0         1
```

Just use `cbind` as above to get the output you expect.

Comment: This is a nice idea. Taking a note now. plus one. :)

Comment: This worked, but whenever I click on the Data in Rstudio the dummy variables don't show up.  Do you know why?

Comment: @Amstell, did you assign the output?

Comment: @AnandaMahto Yes.  As in DF <- cbind(...Could it be because in my original dataset I have 183 variables?

Comment: @Amstell, does `dim(DF)` give you the dimensions you expect? Does `names(DF)` give you the column names you expect? It's a bit hard to say without more details.

Comment: @AnandaMahto I appears to be a limitation in Rstudio.  How would I use this to change the columns to year_2010 and year_2011

Comment: @Amstell, what is the limitation in RStudio? Anyway, I've posted an edit to my `dummyCreator` function that does what you've asked for.

Comment: And I guess R studio has a limitation on the amount of variables it displays in it's browser, which is kind of dumb.  But it's the best solution for linux at the moment

Answer (score 4):

Here is my favorite code for creating dummy variables from a categorical variable.
The only difference is that this code produces `K-1` dummy variable to avoid colinearity:

```
x = as.factor( rep(1:6,each=4) );
model.matrix(~x)[,-1]
```

Substitute `x` with the year from your data set.

Comment: This doesn't work and throws an error with dimensions

Comment: Do not forget to apply `as.factor` to the year column before running the code.

Comment: `model.matrix(~as.factor(DF$year))[,-1]`

Comment: Ok, this works, but I still need this attached to my original dataset to run regressions with.  thanks

Comment: `cbind(DF,model.matrix(~as.factor(DF$year))[,-1])`

Comment: Finally, you can remove `year` from `DF` with `DF$year = NULL`

Answer (score 2):

maybe this?

```
library(tidyr)
DF$row <- 1:nrow(DF)  # to make each row unique
DF$dummy <- 1

newdf <- spread(DF, year, dummy, fill = 0)
```

Comment: This works, but drops the year column out of data.frame

Comment: @Amstell no problem: `newdf$year = DF$year`.

Answer (score 2):

```
 for(i in unique(DF$year)) {
          DF[paste('year',i,sep="")]=DF$year==i
  }
```

Comment: @Amstell no problem: just wrap in `as.numeric()`.

Answer (score 2):

As Andrey Shabalin mentioned, you want [`model.matrix`](http://www.inside-r.org/r-doc/stats/model.matrix).  First you need to convert the `year` column to be a factor.  To get exactly what you want, you need to use [`contr.ltfr`](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/caret/docs/dummyVars), a modified version of [`contr.treatment`](http://www.inside-r.org/r-doc/stats/contr.treatment) in the `caret` package.

In the formula below, `0` means don't use an intercept and `.` represents all the columns in the data frame.

```
DF$year <- factor(DF$year)
model.matrix(
  ~ 0 + ., 
  DF, 
  contrasts.arg = list(year = "contr.ltfr")
)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I have 166 variables in my current dataset and I'm looking for the quickest way to do this, without ifelse and listing out all the variables I want to keep.

Comment: Rather than pasting the formula, you can just make it `~ . + 0`.