# creating dummy variable for years

Tags: r, variables, cut, dummy-data

I have a data with `year` variable 1950-2007, however, each `year` is repeated 12 times because of the "month" variable in the other column. How can i create a year dummy variable? this is what i have and R is not accepting it

```
yeardummy <- cut(research$year, br=c(0, 1950:2007), labels=c("1950:2007"))
```

Comment: Could you show the expected result using a small dataset?  Your labels is a single `string`.  What do you expect it to be?

Comment: If it is a single string, you don't even need `cut`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a function I use for creating multiple dummy variables for each year in my data set.

```
dummyCreator <- function(invec, prefix = NULL) {
     L <- length(invec)
     ColNames <- sort(unique(invec))
     M <- matrix(0L, ncol = length(ColNames), nrow = L,
                 dimnames = list(NULL, ColNames))
     M[cbind(seq_len(L), match(invec, ColNames))] <- 1L
     if (!is.null(prefix)) colnames(M) <- paste(prefix, colnames(M), sep = "_")
     M
} 

#Usage
dummy <- dummyCreator(research$year, prefix = "year")
research <- cbind(research, dummy)
```

Just pass variable from your dataset to it, and any prefix you want and it'll run through, then cbind to original dataset and you're good to go.

Hope this helps.

Comment: A nice thing to do is to [share the source of the functions you use](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27141872/dummy-variable-for-each-year/27142399#27142399).

Comment: @AnandaMahto absolutely.  I forgot who I got it from, so thanks for reminding me.  It's a great function!

Answer (score 0):

I would also do if the expected `dummy` is similar to @Amstell's answer

```
researchNew <- cbind(research, 
       setNames(as.data.frame(model.matrix( ~ 0+factor(year),
        data=research['year'])),paste('year', unique(research$year), sep="_")))
```

#### data

```
research <- data.frame(year=rep(c(1957:1958), each=12), month=rep(month.abb,2))
```